# Standard deviation of difference of two data vectors

Tags: standard-deviation

I have two data vectors A, B where each row of the data represents a pair.

I am looking to find standard deviation of A - B.

The firs approach:

```
stdev(A - B)
```

Second approach:

```
sqrt(var(A) + var(B) - 2*rho*stdev(A)*stdev(B))
```

where `rho` is the correlation of A and B

I am not sure what is the difference of the two approaches. i.e which one is better and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.
Proof by definition of variance and the linearity of expectation:
$$Var(A-B) = E[(A-B)^2] - E^2[A-B] = $$
$$E[A^2] - 2E[AB] + E[B^2] - E[A]^2 - E[B^2] + 2E[A]E[B] = $$
$$E[A^2] - E[A]^2 + E[B^2]- E[B^2]- 2E[AB] + 2E[A]E[B] = $$
$$Var[A] + Var[B] - 2COV(A,B)$$
where
$$COV(A,B) = \rho\sigma_A\sigma_B$$